# Wordpress 404 all pages except home

Tags: 404-error, server

I know this question might be a repeat or duplicate of another post.
I've been getting this error after shortly migrating the domain from `http` to `https`.

I've been following multiple questions and answers like this [one right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182534/wordpress-is-giving-me-404-page-not-found-for-all-pages-except-the-homepage) but none of them seem to work.

Solutions i've tried:
-> disable all plugins and enable them again
-> change `.htaccess` file to the default wordpress
-> change permalink structure to the default one again.

None of the above solutions worked for me now, although they worked in the past for a different website.

All pages give me `404 document not found in the server` except the homepage.

thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The problem does not happen if i use the default permalink structure and if use the following code in the wp-config:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://websiteurl'); 
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://websiteurl');

//define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

Comment: what did you do to migrate from http -> https? Did you just change the setting in wordpress Settings -> General?

Comment: So Basically , the devops of my team updated the http certificate and moved it to a new  domain, but under the same url. The problem has been fixed but only if the wordpress permalink structure is the default one, i've tried to use the /%category%/%postname% and it doesn't work :(

Comment: See the new edit please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the website url in the database on the table `wp_options`

Seems like it didn't change even after i change the url in the backend, i had to change it manually.